# cannot compile latest gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I have Linux CentOS 6.3 and gcc installed version 4.4.7 which is ancient.  I wanted to install the latest gcc.

I downloaded and unzipped it and when I tried

```
>./configure
```

it said I needed GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+

I installed these successfully and then when I tried to `./configure` gcc again, now I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To this I have not yet been able to google a working solution.

What to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this immediate error with

```
>./configure  --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib
```

but then there are other errors.

Comment: The dependency avalanche is the usual result of trying to install recent software on these distros that have been frozen in a long distant past. And If you succeed you end up with something where half the software has been rebuilt and you aren't even sure that everything really works together (which is the purpose of using a distro). It can be easier and less risky to just upgrade to a more recent version.

Answer (score 1):

> /usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file

```
# yum provides */crt1.o
# yum install gcc-c++ glibc-devel glibc-headers kernel-headers
```

Besides that it's not a good idea to replace the system compiler. Please don't. And you can get multiple extra compilers:  devtoolset-3 , -4 , -6 →

```
# yum install centos-release-scl-rh centos-release-scl
# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++ devtoolset-4-gcc-c++ devtoolset-6-gcc-c++
```

Provides gcc, g++ version 4.9.2 and gcc, g++ version 5.3.1, and gcc, g++ version 6.3.1 
https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/

Note : gcc-7.x will not build with CentOS 6.x, AFAIK. The OS is too old. Example configuring gcc-5.3 :

```
../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc53 --program-suffix=53 --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib
```

( rpm package is available: gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbTBneHgwSzBodFE/view?usp=sharing )